# CXJS access elements by ID after rendering?

Tags: cxjs

I have an I-Frame with embedded content.

```
import {HtmlElement, Link, Section} from 'cx/widgets';
import Controller from './Controller'

export default <cx>
   <h2 putInto="header">
      Home
   </h2>

   <Section mod="card" controller={Controller}>
       <iframe style='border:1px' src:bind="$page.url" id="contentFrame"  width="100%"></iframe>

   </Section>

</cx>
```

As i-frames need a height in pixels i use a controller to apply a resize-listener and need to initially set iframes high directly.

```
import { Controller } from 'cx/ui';   

export default class extends Controller {
    onInit() {    

        var url = "https://myContentUrl/?foo=bar&PHPSESSID=" + currentDashboard.customData.session + "&someMore=1";

        this.store.init("$page",{url:url});

        window.onresize = function(event) {
            document.getElementById("contentFrame").height = window.innerHeight-125;
        };

//the following is always null as it seems not to be initialised yet.
       document.getElementById("contentFrame").height = window.innerHeight-125;


   }    
}
```

How can I set the initial hight of the iframe? References like react also dont work. It is sure not intended, that a user needs to resize the browsers window to get a full size i-frame. ;)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is commonly solved using CSS flexbox applied on Section's `bodyStyle`.

https://fiddle.cxjs.io/?f=Kjarwesn

The section needs to have an explicit height set which can be specified in pixels, relative to viewport height (vh) or again using flexbox.

```
<Section
      title="Section"
      mod="card"
      style="height: 50vh; border: 1px solid red"
      bodyStyle="display: flex; flex-direction: column"
    >
      <iframe src="..." style="flex: 1 1 0%" />
</Section>
```